# ¿Cómo puedo generar una tabla a partir de los datos de un array?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, table

estoy practicando algunos ejercicios de JavaScript y me he topado con un problema.

Ahora mismo tengo un array con ciertas palabras,  las cuales deseo utilizar para generar una tabla HTML desde JavaScript. Sin embargo, cada vez que lo intento, o me da error o me sale algo que no es lo que buscaba.

Supongamos que tengo un array con las siguientes palabras: "ciclismo, natación, gastronomía, tenis, baloncesto, fútbol, cine, tecnología, turismo, política".

Pues bien, a partir de ese array quiero generar una tabla con 10 filas (que es la suma de los elementos de dicho array). Sé que se puede hacer mediante DOM o mediante `document.write`. En este caso, estoy intentando hacerlo con `document.write` y un bucle `for`.

El resultado que busco es algo así como:

```html
    AFICIONES
    
    array[0]
    array[1]
    array[2]
    array[3]
    array[4]
    array[5]
    array[6]
    array[7]
    array[8]
    array[9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `forEach` para recorrer la colección (en este caso tu array) fácilmente sin necesidad de conocer el número de elementos que tienes.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("target");
let arr = ['ciclismo', 'natación', 'gastronomía', 'tenis', 'baloncesto', 'fútbol', 'cine', 'tecnología', 'turismo', 'política'];
arr.forEach((el, index)=>{
  table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+ el +"</td></tr>";
});
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="target">
    <tr>
        <td>AFICIONES</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el `for` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Y dentro del mismo, podrás obtener la posicion dinámica del array para ir armando la tabla.

```js
var arr = ['Deportes', 'Gastronomía', 'Fapping', 'Música'];
var arrayLength = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i])
}
```